# UAT version of app best practice

Tags: production-environment, ibm-cloud, dev-to-production, uat

I am looking to create a UAT/Development version of an app we have. So any changes needed can be done there before making the changes on the original 'production' app.

What is the best way to do this on Bluemix? Is it best to simply fork the project on Dev Ops or is there a way to easily set up a new app to mirror the original. I tried creating a new URL route within the app but although named differently any changes i made update both URLs.

I just wondered what peoples experience with doing this was and how best they managed this?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your source in a git repository, with two branches "master" and "development". You can set up a different DevOps Services pipeline for each brach. One pipeline will pick up new commits from "development" branch and push the app to myapp-dev.mybluemix.net. When you're ready to promote to production, you can merge changes to "master" branch, and the other pipeline will pick up those changes and push to myapp.mybluemix.net

Hope this makes sense. It's just one way you can do this.

[Rule #1 of the 12 Factor App - One codebase tracked in revision control, many deploys](http://12factor.net/codebase) -

Keep in mind that you can create multiple spaces in Bluemix. You can make a space called "dev" with all your applications in development, and another space called "production" for all your production apps. You can manage access control this way.